# maven pom.xml exclude pattern with $

Tags: maven, pom.xml

Just want to know what exactly is the meaning of following exclude pattern in pom.xml ?

```
 <configuration>
              <excludes>
                  <exclude>**/*$*</exclude>
               </excludes>
 </configuration>
```

Answer (score 2):

I can only guess - this is for removing  inner classes from plugin.

Comment: Just curious, is "**/*$*" for regex purpose?

Comment: Inner class after compiling look like this: `Outer$Inner.class`